# Confidence interval for success probability in negative binomial experiment

Tags: confidence-interval, negative-binomial-distribution

Suppose I have a biased coin (heads with probability p), and I keep flipping it until I get t tails. So I had to flip n times in total to get t tails. How do I find a (frequentist) confidence interval for the probability of heads p?

Comment: First hit when Googling "negative binomial confidence interval": http://www.bepress.com/ucbbiostat/paper242/ (abstract only).  The seventh hit gets you a full paper along with its references to the literature: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0000180 .

Comment: I downvoted the question because it's eminently google-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for ML estimation (which may or may not be what you want) please check the `fitdistr` function in the `MASS`library in `R`. This function can estimate the unknown parameters using ML estimation. But please be careful about the parametrization of the negative binomial distribution of `MASS`. Apart from estimating the unknown parameters, it gives the confidence intervals for the estimates.

HTH
S.